# Spring JPA: Cause path expected for join

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm using Spring jpa to get data from two tables, but when I get data with query, it happen an error..

two table: Trip and Trip Status

My model:
my entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="trip")
public class Trip {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="id")
private int id;

@Column(name="start_address")
private String start_address;

@Column(name="end_address") 
private String end_address;

@Column(name="pickup_latitude")
private float pickup_latitude;

@Column(name="pickup_longitude")
private float pickup_longitude;

@Column(name="fee")
private float fee;

@Column(name="canceled_by")
private String canceled_by; 

@Column(name="canceled_at")
private Instant canceled_at;        

@Column(name="actual_distance")
private float actual_distance;

@Column(name="actual_price")
private float actual_price;     

/////////////////////////////////////////////
@Column(name="estimated_distance")
private float estimated_distance;

@Column(name="estimated_time")
private float estimated_time;

@Column(name="estimated_price")
private float estimated_price;

@Column(name="actual_time")
private float actual_time;

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@NotNull
private TripStatus tripStatus;

// getter and setter
```

my repository:

```
 @Repository
 public interface TripRepository extends JpaRepository<Trip, Integer> {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub  
@Query("SELECT trip FROM Trip trip INNER JOIN trip_status ON trip.trip_status_id = trip_status.id WHERE trip_status.id =: id")
public List<Trip> findById(@Param("id") int id);

  }
```

When I run it happen the problem with exception following as:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join! [SELECT trip FROM com.model.Trip trip INNER JOIN trip_status ON trip.trip_status_id = trip_status.id WHERE trip_status.id =: id]
```

How to fix the problem?

Comment: You can’t combine JPQL ( trip) and Native SQL (trip_status) in one query. Need use TripStatus there

Answer (score 0):

JPQL is a JPA Query Language. It works in a oriented object way, so  you cant confuse trip_status (column name) with tripStatus (entity attribute name).

First: your Join should be `INNER JOIN trip.tripStatus ts`

Second: In JPQL, you dont have to specify `trip.trip_status_id = trip_status.id`

finally: `WHERE ts.id = :id`

```
@Query("SELECT trip FROM Trip trip INNER JOIN trip.tripStatus ts WHERE ts.id =: id")
```